# Acronis Exchange Recovery: Error 55 (0x410037)

Tags: acronis

Anyone who uses Acronis Exchange know what Acronis Exchange Recovery Error 55 (0x410037) is? Throws it up at every backup. But the backups are still made and I can restore from them? Just annoying getting an error report every day.

(Yes, I have the latest version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Q is pretty old, but to keep things clean and for reference, I wanted to give a resolution. I couldn't get an answer out of Acronis KBs or forums.

I gave up on Acronis for backups, this was one of a number of experiences that I had with their backup software that was frustrating. Got a refund (had to fight for that) and moved to Barracuda, and have better success with their products.

One thing about Acronis compared to Barracuda was the return policy. Barracuda has a 30 day full return policy, whereas Acronis has nothing like that. That says something.

Still use Acronis products for cloning purposes.